# should we avoid to use spring managed bean when it is unnecessary?

Tags: java, spring, refactoring, mockito, static-methods

Say I have a relative complex class which needs to be simplified by breaking into few smaller helper classes. One suggested refactor solution is :

```
public class RefactoredComplexClass {
    private final Helper1 h1;
    private final Helper2 h2;
    // Helper1 and Helper2 will be injected by spring IoC
    public RefactoredComplexClass(Helper1 h1, Helper2 h2) {
        this.h1 = h1; this.h2 = h2;
    }
} 
public class Helper1 {// no state class
    public int add(int x, int y) { return x + y ; }
}
```

The reason behind above suggestion is mainly for making mockito based test easy.

My question is :
1. Should static method rather than instance method be used for those no state helper class?
2. Is it a good idea to inject those Helper object?

My own thought on this is static method should be used since there is no state to maintain for those helper class/method. And it is unneccessary to inject those helper classes' instances. But I do agree to extent that above solution making mockito based testing easier given the fact that static method is hard to mock.

Any suggestion?

Comment: It certainly seems a good idea to decouple a manager/user of operations from the operation (helper) classes.  You say there is no state for those operation instances but that's a choice of your implementation.  I could easily imagine many scenarios where you would instantiate several versions with corresponding state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your example, it seems that static methods would be the way to go, i.e. if you are sure the helper classes would be absolutely stateless and you can test the static methods well and all the methods in those classes are just bunch of utility methods. (e.g. java.lang.Math) 
Few Considerations for Static methods:
1) Static bound and better performance. 
2) No Object creation.
3) Methods can't be overridden
4) Difficult to mock 
5) Early initialization
Considerations for Spring based Singleton (The Stateless helpers are best made singleton and injected into your class)
1) You would have at least one Object - You benefit from inheritance, polymorphism etc
2) Can be lazily loaded
3) Easy to mock test

You can read up this [useful article](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/03/difference-between-singleton-pattern-vs-static-class-java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hi ^^ Would you like to change / specify / give different Helpers ?

If so :

> 1 : You are using the visitor pattern ( Helpers are in fact here
>   visitors)... This is a good pattern, even if it may generate many
>   classes. It let you change the behaviour of your
>   RefactoredComplexClass without touching its code, even at runtime, and
>   that is great.
>
> Instead, using static method is simpler but to change behaviour, you
>   need to Override your RefactoredComplexClass.
>
> Well in general I prefer composition to extensions...
>
> 2 : That is not a bad idea at all... It let you specify the bahviour
>   of your class from Spring file.

In other case it can indeed be a good idea to keep it simple.